# View raw markdown of GitHub comment

Tags: github

How can I view the Markdown of a comment in a GitHub issue? For example, I would like to see the Markdown that makes up this comment:
https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3857#issue-116738665

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the first post is the actual issue itself, not accessible but the [GitHub issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#list-comments-on-an-issue):

https://api.github.com/repos/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3857/comments

That list only 3 comments, since the first post is not a comment.

The issue itself has a formatted body:

https://api.github.com/repos/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3857

That returns:

````
  "body": "In Safari , pass a path using unicode string to `navigate` method  like this\r\n\r\n```js\r\nBackbone.history.navigate('/city/北京',{trigger:true});\r\n```\r\nThe hash is incorrect. It output\r\n\r\n```js\r\nlocation.hash\r\n//> #/city/%17%AC\r\n```\r\n\r\nI tracked the code, it caused by `_updateHash` method.\r\n\r\nThe call stack created by  `History.prototype.navigate` method like this\r\n\r\n* navigate\r\n   -  decodeFragment\r\n   - _updateHash\r\n\r\nThe fragment passed to `_updateHash`,  was decoded by `decodeFragment`, so the hash was incorrect。\r\n\r\nI also searched the commit history, the `decodeFragment` added in \"1.2.0\"\r\n\r\nPS: My english is not good, although I am trying to improve\r\n\r\n",
````

That is not *exactly* mardown:

````
    In Safari , pass a path using unicode string to `navigate` method  like this

```js\r\nBackbone.history.navigate('/city/北京',{trigger:true});
```\r\nThe hash is incorrect. It output

```js\r\nlocation.hash
//> #/city/%17%AC
```

I tracked the code, it caused by `_updateHash` method.

The call stack created by  `History.prototype.navigate` method like this

* navigate
   -  decodeFragment
   - _updateHash
The fragment passed to `_updateHash`,  was decoded by `decodeFragment`, so the hash was incorrect。
I also searched the commit history, the `decodeFragment` added in \"1.2.0\"
PS: My english is not good, although I am trying to improve
````

[The second comment](https://api.github.com/repos/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3857/comments) in this issue has two images, so those fancy effects are no  markdow:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/516562/11164567/62f9ddf6-8b2f-11e5-8aa8-631c1aa84422.gif

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/516562/11164567/62f9ddf6-8b2f-11e5-8aa8-631c1aa84422.gif]

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/leexiaosi/uyp3o6ek/](https://jsfiddle.net/leexiaosi/uyp3o6ek/)

**notice!!!** : please open in safari.

### the record of safari
![safari](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/516562/11164567/62f9ddf6-8b2f-11e5-8aa8-631c1aa84422.gif)

### the record of chrome
![chrome](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/516562/11164583/c66d1b82-8b2f-11e5-9d88-ecba16ae6167.gif)
```

Comment: I guess that's the best I'm going to get.

Answer (score 13):

Simply replace username, reponame and issue number in the following url:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/issues/NUMBER/comments
```

[Here](https://api.github.com/repos/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3857/comments)'s an example

Comment: For quick reference, you can get the body (which is the markdown) of the `n`th comment by pasting this in the browser console `await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/:username/:reponame/issues/:issue_id/comments').then(resp => resp.json()).then(comments => comments[n].body)`

Answer (score 4):

You can see the raw markdown by using "Quote reply" (found after clicking three dots at top right of a comment.

Here's the beginning of the comment you asked for:

> In Safari , pass a path using unicode string to `navigate` method like this
>
> ```js
> Backbone.history.navigate('/city/北京',{trigger:true});
> ```
>
> The hash is incorrect. It output
>
> ```js
> location.hash
> //> #/city/%17%AC
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: This works for the comment the original poster mentioned, but it didn't work for me for https://github.com/VSpaceCode/VSpaceCode/issues/173#issuecomment-776388616.

Comment: You're right, it's not catching the `kbd` tag: `<kbd>q</kbd>`

Answer (score 3):

It's probably late. But I could somewhat do it this way (at least in firefox).

I am assuming your intention is to copy the formatting of the comment.

This is not an exact solution, but since GitHub supports HTML tags in comments, this will work just fine.

1. Right click somewhere at the top of the comment you want to copy.
2. Inspect element
3. In the Inspect Element box, you will find a line that's a few lines above the highlighted line which has this code:

   `<td class="d-block comment-body markdown-body  js-comment-body">`
4. Right click on the line having the above code
5. Select Copy>Inner HTML

Now you can either paste this in a comment box, preview it and you'll be able to see the same formatting, OR use an [online HTML to MD converter](https://domchristie.github.io/to-markdown/).

Answer (score 0):

This **kinda** shows the markdown part correctly:

```bash
echo -e $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/issues/NUMBER/comments)
```

`echo -e` interprets the various `\n` present in `body` and displays them as newlines.