# How to view source code for markdown in a github issue?

Tags: github

Github issues are written in github flavored markdown.

Whenever composing an issue (or commenting on an existing issue), there is the option to choose between 'Write' (the markdown) and 'Preview' (rendered)

However, this is not possible for published issues/comments on issues (only while composing can you view the 'Write' (i.e. raw markdown) code.

Is there anyway to get the raw markdown code for published issues / comments on issues?

Comment: "Quote reply" (three dots at top right of comment) seems to show the Markdown, is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View raw markdown of GitHub comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106821/view-raw-markdown-of-github-comment)

Comment: @JBallin it did, perfectly. Thanks. FWIW I put a (much more concise) version below

Answer (score 1):

Replace username, reponame and issue number in the following url:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/issues/NUMBER/comments
```

[Here](https://api.github.com/repos/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3857/comments)'s an example